# Add an option with an optional argument to a command in a mercurial extension

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-extension

I want to add an option to the mercurial command hg incomming and a specific behavior. Here is what I've done:

```
entry = extensions.wrapcommand(commands.table, 'incoming', specific_behavior)
entry[1].append(('', 'newopt', '', _('NEW OPT HELP STRING'), _('OPTION_ARGUMENT')))
```

Currently the OPTION_ARGUMENT is required but I want it optional. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: How does it fail if you don't pass it? (With `--traceback`.) AFAICT it mostly depends on your `specific_behavior()` function.

Comment: The specific_behavior() function is never called. Mercurial just answer me : hg incoming: option --newopt requires argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only default values allowed are `None`, `True` or `False`. So if you set the default value `''` a value has to be passed in that will be passed to your function as a string.

http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/tip/mercurial/fancyopts.py#l85

Comment: Thanks you. It seems to be my solution.